# Consolidating Rails Migrations on a Long Running Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm working on a project that's accumulated hundreds of migrations, and I'm unsure what to do with them long term. I suppose they're no hurting anything, but it seems strange to keep around a bunch of old files for incremental migrations, some of them creating tables that are later removed.

So far, I've seen three possibilities:

1. Leave them alone. They're not hurting anything.
2. Just delete them. I don't see much harm in doing this, since a new developer would be probably be starting with schema load anyway, not migrations.
3. Delete them all, create a new one with a timestamp matching an old merge, and create a new merge from your schema. This seems very clean, but I'm not sure who would actually use it.

I'm inclined to just delete them, but I'm curious if there's a big pitfall I'm missing.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, as soon as every database on the project, especially the production, are at least at version '201xxxxxxxx', it should be fine to delete migrations before that version. They are not technically necessary anymore.

After that, if you want to play archaeology with your database history, you can still use your version control system.

With **Git** for example, you can use the following commands to have a quick look over the past :

```
git log --name-only db/migrate/    #to list commit involving migrations + migration filename
git show xxxxx db/migrate          #to see the code of commit xxxxx's migration(s)
```

Alternatively, you can browse repository history of `schema.rb`, identify a commit and see the corresponding migration content with the command above.

If you prefer to have a lighter `db/migrate` and use Version control, I would go for a little cleanup.

If you find it more convenient to have the whole migrations history directly available because it's easier to browse, I would go for option 1.

**Note**: it is very likely that old migrations do not make sense with the current application code. For example, some migrations may refer to class or methods that don't exist anymore.
Using version control to checkout the application at the time the migration was written could also avoid some confusion.

Comment: +1 for version control. That's where you should be going for your project's history.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I lean toward option 1: It's generally true that at some point in any project, the schema is what matters, and the migrations are just a curiosity, but you're right when you say they're not hurting anything. Theoretically the old migrations could be useful for someone who wanted to go back and see how the database was organized at some point in the past.

I don't know of any serious pitfalls in deleting them, but I also don't see an advantage to doing so, unless it's the saving of time scrolling past them when you want to edit a new migration.

I don't think the effort of putting together a single migration that duplicates the schema is beneficial - it's extra work, and that's what the schema is for anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you work on a project large enough for long enough, there will come a time when you look at all of those extra migrations with disdain and wonder how so many can exist.

You think to yourself, "just delete them...they don't *do* anything."  This is a perfectly logical and normal thought process (especially as a Rails developer, we just love to minimize code and make things efficient!), but don't let the dark side tempt you.

By deleting migrations, you are deleting the historical record of your application's data model, and worse, the logical path you took to get to your current model.  This history can help you remember why you did what you did, and didn't do what you didn't do.

Yes, we've all been guilty of deleting migrations from time to time.  But you must resist the temptation as the net benefit would only be a few kB and a cleaner migration folder.

Remember:
Those who delete migrations are condemned to repeat them!

Comment: Lots of migrations don't scale well at all. If you want an historical record you have your source control history.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our former projects we dropped all migrations, created a new one which would truncate schema_migrations table with manual sql and then copied db/schema.rb contents to it.
Surely this migration is irreversible, however it allowed us to get rid of hundreds of old valueless migrations but still be able to re-create db not from db schema only but from migrations as well.